# how to make #key and @key clickable in IOS7

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

Anyone knows how I can make the #KEY and @NAME clickable in the text of comments in IOS7 (the same way that instagram does it for example)?  i am trying to use NSMutableAttributedString but I'm not sure how to detect click event, in the image below clicking @Username should take the user to the profile of the user

[image]

Comment: where does the "tags" appear ? in an App ? in `UITextField` ?

Comment: hi @ShivanRaptor it happens In the App. basically if a user type #key in their comment, when that comment is rendered, we want to click on #key and get some search result for it

Comment: when you said comment, is it sort of web-based in UIWebView ? I'm confused. Better show us codes & screenshots.

Comment: i added the screenshot

Comment: IIRC, during the WWDC sessions I've seen them talk about a new API in TextKit that allows to find the range of text the user has tapped. That'd seem to fit perfectly, but I can't seem to find more info right now, and it's iOS 7 only.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel, a stable, well-maintained UILabel subclass that provides the functionality you're looking for out of the box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the [`UITextViewDelegate` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:), there is a new method in iOS7: `textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:`.

You didn't share any code, but it is safe to assume you have an `attributedString` and a `range` representing the area you turned blue.  I'll also assume you can extract the username into a variable called `username`.

With these three pieces of information, you add a link attribute to that range.

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName
                         value:[@"username://" stringByAppendingString:username]
                         range:range];
```

In your delegate, you could do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{
    if ([URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"username"]) {
        [self doSomethingWithUserName:URL.host];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I believe they demoed this in the Introducing Text Kit session at WWDC 2013.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML links and render it using [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

`<div>
      Here goes the text. <a href="/users/Username">@Username</a> <a href="/tags/mytag">#mytag</a>.
  </div>`

When a user clicks a link, the web view's delegate method [`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a) is called. There you can get the URL from the request and do whatever you want. It's important to return `NO` from this method, otherwise the web view tries to load the request.

Comment: I used this approach in one of my Apps, and this is the most simple approach which works across most of iOS versions (including old ones). The side effect is, the loading speed is slow (unless things are pre-rendered before showing up to user), and the size of `UIWebView` has to do extra resize if it is not fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) which offers link buttons what you can add to attributed text. It's based around HTML parsing so you'll need to do a little extra work with the parsing to determine where the link buttons should go.

Alternatively you could add a pat gesture recognizer to the comment view. When a tap is detected you can use `<UITextInput>` to find out what text was tapped on and if it is a 'link'.