# iOS Instagram Tags Text Layout? How Is It Done?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, xib

I've always been curious how instagram gets it's tags to layout fluidly and wanted to know what goes behind this functionality? To me, it seems like they're using UIButton's and just calculating placement of the buttons line by line? Is that right? Or is there a simpler method of doing it without having to manual calculate the placement of each tag line by line / or side by side given that multiple tag's width's fit together?

Or, are they using NSAttributedStrings?

Any ideas?

Here's an example of the layout I'm referring to.

[image]

Comment: I've used https://github.com/domness/DWTagList it works for me and very simple to work with. hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified way to do it using UITextView and NSAttributedString:

1. Use regular expressions to get character ranges for links.
2. Add link styling to the matched ranges.
3. Add custom attribute to range that references tap action to execute.
4. On touch, if index of character is inside a matched range, change the link formatting to highlight it and run the associated tap action.

How to get index of character at location in iOS7:

```
- (NSUInteger) getCharIndexAt: (CGPoint) location
{
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = self.layoutManager;
    NSUInteger characterIndex = NSNotFound;
    characterIndex = [layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:location inTextContainer:self.textContainer fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:NULL];

    return characterIndex;
}
```

Also check out WWDC 2013 intro to TextKit Demo

[ios7 text utilities](https://gist.github.com/alexlavr/7064429)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm currently working on `NSAttributedString` and `UITextView` to get all this working, and my current code can do it. So I'm going to explain a possible version of doing this.
Here are the tips and big steps, with iOS7:
`NSAttributedString`, in iOS7 has a new attribute : `NSLinkAttributeName`. You can add it to your `NSAttributedString`, and with a detection method (combining: [how to make #key and @key clickable in IOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299556/how-to-make-key-and-key-clickable-in-ios7) and [Get word from tap in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884520/get-word-from-tap-in-uitextview)) you can manage it. That's for the general way of doing it. For previous version, you'll have to do a little more of work, but keeping this general idea.
But since, it only for hashtags, since you can detect the world behind the tap, you can do this: Detect what word has been tapped (see previous links), detect if this word has an hashtag, and if yes, you can do whatever action you want. You can play with a `NSRegularExpression` to know where are the hashtags, and know when to "color" them.

Comment: Hmm interesting. In my specific situation I'm curious to know if I can do it easier with a loop since I have the ability to get all the #keys within a single NSString with each delmited by a comma as that's how the api I'm using returns associated tags? So I don't have to scan for the tags like the attributed string approach seems to do?

Comment: Well, a part of the work I talked before is to separate (rendering blue for example) what's an hashtag and what's "normal text", that's why I get through NSAttribuedString.