# How to make a word clickable UITextView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Is there a way to create a `UITextView` with word clickable.

When I will click on the word then word will be highlighted. Please refer below image.

[image: effect]

Comment: Yes it is possible but how you know which word is clickable ?

Comment: With UITapGestureRecognizer I can found the location of the tapped word, then calc the textrange, finally get the word with that textrange. I found some solutions by search "ios uitextview get tapped word"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779946/ios-instagram-tags-text-layout-how-is-it-done ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043006/swift-tap-on-a-part-of-text-of-uilabel

Answer (score 1):

```
     let textTest = "I have read and agree with the Privacy Policy & Terms and Conditions"

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapLabel))

    textTest.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    textTest.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

   @IBAction func tapLabel(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let text = (textTest)!
    let termsRange = (text as NSString).range(of: "Terms and Conditions")
    let privacyRange = (text as NSString).range(of: "Privacy Policy")

    if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: attributeLabel, inRange: termsRange) {
        print("Tapped terms")
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TermsConditionViewController") as! TermsConditionViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    } else if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: attributeLabel, inRange: privacyRange) {
        print("Tapped privacy")
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PrivacyPolicyViewController") as! PrivacyPolicyViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    } else {
        print("Tapped none")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. But I have a question,  so if I want every word clickable, then I have to make every word as a range?

Comment: let typeCasteToStringFirst = textField.text as NSString?
let newString = typeCasteToStringFirst?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
You can try with this.

Comment: Sure No issues.